# TableAdapter Configuration Wizard cannot recognize sql statement "DATE()"

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, report

I need to make a report in my program.
Then, I use this sql code to filter the data that will be displayed in the report viewer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order 
WHERE OrDate=DATE() OR OrDate>=DATE() - 7;
```

When I clicked next, this error occurs

> Generated SELECT statement.
>   Error in WHERE clause near ')'.
>   Unable to parse query text.

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: First of all, you don't need OrDate=DATE() as that just tests for today, when you have OrDate>=DATE() - 7 that tests for anything starting 1 week ago, including today. Second, even if it doesn't fix your problem, change the reserved word "order" as it's just good practice. And third, try putting the (DATE() - 7) in parentheses as Adam suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting Date to return todays date? I thought that was GETDATE() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188383.aspx

if you are on SQL server 2008

select 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Order] 
    WHERE OrDate >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))

Comment: `GETDATE()` is for `SQL Server`.

Comment: ah, just noticed the comment - MS Access

Comment: I want to display 1 week dates.

Comment: is it as simple as you are missing brackets around the Date()-7 => "WHERE OrDate = DATE() OR  OrDate >= (DATE() - 7)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because of `DATE()` but because of the tablename `ORDER`.

In most RDBMS, `ORDER` is a reserved keyword. When using reserved keywords, escape it using delimiters which is vendor specific. In `SQL Server`, you can use brackets.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM   [Order] 
WHERE  OrDate = DATE() OR 
       OrDate >= DATE() - 7;
```

- [Access Reserved Keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

From Access Docs,

> If a reserved word is already in use, you can avoid error messages by
>   surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets ([ ]). However,
>   the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

Comment: what's the error message? `DATE()` is valid. see here [Use current date and time in calculations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/use-current-date-and-time-in-calculations-HP001098479.aspx)

Comment: This is the error message.
Generated SELECT statement. Error in WHERE clause near ')'. Unable to parse query text.

Comment: what version of access you are using? have you already wrap the table name with brackets?

Comment: I changed the name of the table from Order to OrderItems to avoid using reserved keywords, but nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried using `BETWEEN`? eg, `...WHERE OrDate BETWEEN (DATE() - 7) AND DATE()`?

Comment: I tested this query and it works as is (with [] around Order as @JW mentioned.  Since it seems like you are generating this query in C# perhaps you should just build your query string with the actual date values instead of relying on the date functions.  You'll probably still have to surround dates with # per normal Access protocol.  Also the actual condition you have doesn't make sense since OrDate>=DATE() - 7 includes OrDate=Date()